# Magento Google Analytics Code is not showing

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I am new to magento and I have placed my account number in my system > Configuration > Sales > Google API. I have also enabled Google Analytics. But still I can't see the Google Analytics code on any of my magento application. What I have double checked are:

1. Account Number are proper (These are for the same domain name for which we are trying).
2. Google Analytics is Enabled (Yes).

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? If so it might be missing an important placeholder that would show where the analytics code should go.

Comment: yes, I am using that and I do agree that you might be correct on this, checking this thing now. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same here. It turns out that the problem was caused by my customized theme that was developed for magento 1.5 and now is applied to 1.7.

In app/design/frontend/mytheme/layout/googleanalytics.xml i had:

```
    <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
```

And it should be:

```
    <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
```

Comment: awesome 1 saved lot of time:)

Answer (score 2):

Have just checked and the google analytics code is normally placed in the `after_body_start` block.
If that block isn't used in your theme or if you just want to follow better practices change that to `before_body_end`. You can find the file "googleanalytics.xml" in your theme's layout directory or in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout`.